# Prevent CKEditor 4.18 from escaping html tags

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a problem with CKEditor replacing <>" as `&lt; &gt; &quot;` respectively when saving contents to database. I would prefer to save the actual html tags in the database instead.
I've tried setting all of the options I could find without any success:

```
config.entities = false;
config.entities_greek = false;
config.entities_latin = false;
config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;
config.entities_processNumerical = false;
```

(Btw, setting `config.entities = true;` encodes the whitespace as `&amp;nbsp;` which is definitely a bug)

So, I figured out I have to deal with `dataProcessor.htmlFilter` and came up with the following code:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
    ev.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
        text: function(text) {
            return text.replace(/\&gt;/, '>').replace(/\&lt;/, '<').replace(/\&quot;/, '"');
        }
    });
});
```

which doesn't help either, because `text` contains the simple text stripped off of all html tags. I was trying to find what other options than `text` I can pass to `addRules()` but couldn't find any information on this in the CKEditor documentation.

Comment: If you also include `config.basicEntities = false;` does it help?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the data processor plugin using the following:

```
 config.removePlugins = 'htmldataprocessor';
```

However, please be aware that this is not advised and is dangerous. Sanitizing HTML inputs to the database protects you against malicious XSS attacks.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Actually, there's even no htmldataprocessor pluign in the plugins directory, so it's not used anyway. I don't mind not sanitizing the HTML, as CKEditor is used only in the backend CMS.